# Turning a type into an interface while using system.func

Tags: c#, interface, delegates

Quite new here and quite new to C# too.
Here is my question.
I have a generic class using func delegate

```
public class Grid<TGridObject>
{
  private TGridObject[,] mat;

  public Grid(int width, int height, System.Func<Grid<TGridObject>, int, int, TGridObject> createObject)
  {
    this.mat= new TGridObject[width, height];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.width; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.height; ++j)
        {
            this.mat[i, j] = createObject(this, i, j);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also defined a very simple class I want to be used by the generic class above:

```
public class PathNode
{
    public Grid<PathNode> Grid { get; set; }

    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public PathNode(Grid<PathNode> grid, int x, int y)
    {
        this.Grid = grid;
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

   //More methods after that

}
```

And, at last, I have a class that uses both previous classes:

```
public class PathFinding
{
    public Grid<PathNode> Grille { get ; set ;}

    public PathFinding(int width, int height)
    {
        this.Grille = new Grid<PathNode>(width, height, (Grid<PathNode> g, int x, int y) => new PathNode(g, x, y));
    }
    //...
}
```

This works fine and I have no particular problem with that.

Now I would like to have more different types of Grid Objects, other than PathNode.
I wanted to have a IPathNode interface, that would be the bases for all that classes.

Defining the interface went good but I cannot figure out how to use it now in the PathFinding class definition.
I tried:

```
public class PathFinding
{
    public Grid<IPathNode> Grille { get ; set ;}

    public PathFinding(int width, int height)
    {
        this.Grille = new Grid<IPathNode>(width, height, (Grid<IPathNode> g, int x, int y) => new IPathNode(g, x, y));
    }
    //...
}
```

But, of course, it throws an error: CS0144 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IPathNode'

I'm stuck. How can I put it right?
Thank you!

Edit: The main idea is to mention in the PathFinding class that it can use a Grid of any type of objects as long as these implement the IPathNode interface. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can't instantiate an interface. You can use an interface as a type parameter, as you did with `Grid<IPathNode>`, but you can only instantiate a class (etc) that *implements* the interface.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. The main idea is to mention in the PathFinding class that it can use a Grid of any type of objects as long as these implement the IPathNode interface.. How can I achieve that?

Comment: In your callback create a concrete class derived from IPathNode then. Currently you try to create an IPathNode there and thats simply not possible. Derive PathNode from IPathNode and create then a PathNode instance there.

Comment: If I derive PathNode from IPathNode and then use PathNode in the PathFinding definition, then I’m stuck with NodePath class. Then, what if I want to use PathFinding class with a grid of another kind of objects, also derived from IPathNode?

Comment: You don't use PathNode you use IPathNode already in PathFinding and thats should work. Or you don't show the problematic part in PathFinding. If you don't want that that class to not now an implementation to create something in th ecallback then delegate that callback even further to someone that is allowed to know.

Comment: Sorry Ralf, I don’t understand. The line that throws and error is this.Grille = new Grid<IPathNode>(width, height, (Grid<IPathNode> g, int x, int y) => new IPathNode(g, x, y)); . How can I change it in any mean that helps me te preserve the versatility of the PathFinding class?

Comment: What kind of grid do you want `Grille` to be initialised to? What should each cell of the grid contain? You need to describe that because that is what the `Grid` constructor wants. If *you* don't even know what objects you want the grid cells to contain, no one does.

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear. I'll try to do my best to explain it. I want the Grille grid to be able to contain any kind of object as far as these objects implement the IPathNode interface. For instance, I will have a PathNode class (that will implement the IPathNode interface) and, let's say a PathNodeWithVisuals class (that will also implement the IPathNode interface). I want the Grid class to be able to contain PathNode type objects or PathNodeWithVisuals objetcs.

Comment: After telling you that, I think that I will go with the generic based solution. My PathFinding class will become a PathFinding<T> where T:IPathNode, new() It should do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the contributors that helped me finding the solution.
I'll share it here.
The idea is to have the PathFinding class able to accept any kind of object as far as these objects implement the IPathNode interface.
So I decided to make the PathFinding class generic:

```
public class PathFinding<T> where T : IPathNode, new()
{ 
    protected Grid<T> grille;

    public Grid<T> Grille { get => this.grille; }

    public PathFinding(int width, int height)
    {
        this.grille = new Grid<T>(width, height, (Grid<T> g, int x, int y) => new T());
    }
}
```

Hope it will help somebody one day!